# Design pattern for iOS JSON

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I'm about to build an iOS app in Swift that communicates with this API and i wanted your advice on the design pattern before building. I am really trying to learn how to create a clean, best in class, MCV design here so any tips are welcome.

I have written a REST API that enables CRUD operations through HTTP on a bunch of resources, lets call them "items". Items have several properties like "name", "type" etc. There are some relations (e.g. "items" are assigned to "users"). Data is presented as JSON.

One of the key things I'm struggling with is where to house the logic for JSON downloading and parsing. Do you put that in the ViewController? Or create a separate controller class? I want to re-use the JSON code for several resources (e.g. "items" and "users"). And do I really need a ItemManager and a ItemViewController?

My current thinking:

- (M) Item - A decodable JSON struct that follows the exact structure of the resource on the API
- (M) User - idem
- (C) JSONController - A class that gets an URL and expected class type, and goes and retrieves the response and returns instances of that class
- (C) ItemManager - A class that would keep track of all the items (by initiating a bunch of instances of Item classes) and use JSON controller to update whenever needed
- (C) UserManager - idem
- (C) ItemViewController - Retrieves the items from ItemManager and prepares them for the view controller; also coordinates button actions etc
- (C) UserViewController - idem
- (V) ItemView - A view that shows the items in a table form
- (V) UserView - idem

Much appreciated and kind regards,
Scott

Comment: Separate responsibilities, better to have many classes with one or a few responsibilities each than the opposite,

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is correct, networking should be done from controllers. However, it is good to keep it separate from view controllers, which it appears is what you are doing with your JSONController class. [Here](https://academy.realm.io/posts/slug-marcus-zarra-exploring-mvcn-swift/) is an interesting article on the "MVC-N" paradigm, which is basically exactly what you're doing: separating the networking components from the view controllers.